# Perform operations on data that has been split into tabls e.g sum of a column in r

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to do operations on data that has been split into tables. The operations should actually affect all tables eg sum of a column

Here is the code I used to split the data frame.

```
library(shiny)





ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("mytabs")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
   df1 <- reactive (split(iris, iris$Species))
  
  output$mytabs <- renderUI({
    
    
    
    thetabs <- lapply(paste0('table_', names(df1())),
                      function(x) {
                        tabPanel(x, 
                                 tableOutput(x))
                      })
    do.call(tabsetPanel, thetabs)
  })
  
  observe({
    lapply(names(df1()), function(x) {
      output[[paste0("table_", x)]] <- renderTable({ df1()[x] })
    })
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: @Julien is there a way I can get the sum of a column and present it the sum in a valuebox

Comment: @Julien is there a way I can get the sum of a column in the tables that are produced after the split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can add a `bslib::value_box` in the same tabPanel that the tableOutput goes.

Here's an example, notice the use of map2 instead of lapply, this is to loop through the character with the name of the tables and the tables themselves.

```
    thetabs <- purrr::map2(
      paste0("table_", names(df1())),
      df1(),
      function(x, y) {
        tabPanel(
          title = x,
          value_box(
            title = glue::glue("Sum of {x}"), 
            value = sum(y[['Sepal.Length']]),
            showcase = bs_icon("plus")
          ),
          tableOutput(x)
        )
      }
    )
```

App:

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(bsicons)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("mytabs")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  df1 <- reactive(split(iris, iris$Species))

  output$mytabs <- renderUI({
    thetabs <- purrr::map2(
      paste0("table_", names(df1())),
      df1(),
      function(x, y) {
        tabPanel(
          title = x,
          value_box(
            title = glue::glue("Sum of {x}"), 
            value = sum(y[['Sepal.Length']]),
            showcase = bs_icon("plus")
          ),
          tableOutput(x)
        )
      }
    )
    do.call(tabsetPanel, thetabs)
  })

  observe({
    lapply(names(df1()), function(x) {
      output[[paste0("table_", x)]] <- renderTable({
        df1()[x]
      })
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```